# How to view two different jasper report in a single Jasper Report using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Suppose I have two different jasper dynamic report which works fine when I view them using Spring MVC controller with two different jasper view name but I want both of them in one jasper report as a single view. Is there any way to merge both of them in a single report.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dashboard` with your two different reports and can render it as single view inside your webpage but do note that this solution only works on **Professional/Enterprise edition** of Jasper Reports.